# How to loop through file and count specific values in perl?

Tags: file, perl

Let's say I have a file with the lines such as:

```
*some numbers* :00: *somenumbers*
*somenumbers* :21: *somenumbers*
```

And for every number between `::` I need to count how many times it repeats in the file?

```
while (<>){     
    chomp($_);
    my ($nebitno,$bitno,$opetnebitno) = split /:/, $_;
    $count{$bitno}++;
}
foreach $bitno(sort keys %count){
    print $bitno," ",$count{bitno}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: (a) What have you tried? (b) Are those the only places colons occur on a line?  Can a line have more than one `:\d+:` sequence? (c) If you have multiple files specified on the command line, do you want the count for each file, or for the files in aggregate?

Comment: (a) Im new to perl and have tried putting the values into a list, then increasing some counters but it does not look promising at all (b) yes those are the only places colons occur a line only has one : : sequence (c) i want to count for each file

Comment: I repeat: what have you tried?  Show us!  There are many ways to do it — this is Perl, so TMTOWDTI (There's More Than One Way To Do It).  What have you tried?  You should probably be using a hash indexed by the number strings; you could use a plain array.  Are the numbers always 2-digit numbers, or can they be bigger, smaller?  Negative?  With a positive sign?  If with positive, do `10` and `+10` count as 1 or 2 different numbers?

Comment: This does not take into consideration that multiple files can be specified

Comment: OK; other than not handling multiple file, and the absence of `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, that's a decent job.  (Always use both sets of `use`, at least until you've been programming Perl longer than I have (1992, or maybe a little earlier) — I don't trust my scripts until they're clean with those `use` options; I'm not that good of a Perl programmer.

Comment: Do you want to reset the counts at each new file?

Comment: @Shawn: Yes — the OP said so in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450519/how-to-loop-through-file-and-count-specific-values-in-perl/61451007#comment108703704_61450519).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you produced was not bad code — it did the job for a single file at a time. Adapting the code shown in the question to handle multiple files, resetting the counts after each file:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %count = ();

while (<>) {     
    my ($nebitno, $bitno, $opetnebitno) = split /:/, $_;
    $count{$bitno}++;
}
continue
{
    if (eof) {
        print "$ARGV:\n";
        foreach $bitno (sort keys %count) {
            print "$bitno $count{bitno}\n";
        }
        %count = ();
    }
}
```

The key here is the `continue` block, and the `if (eof)` test.  You can use `close $ARGV` in a continue block to reset `$.` (the line number) when the file changes; it is a common use for it.  This sort of per-file summary is another use.  The other changes are cosmetic.  You don't need to chomp the line (though there's no particular harm done if you do); I print whole strings rather than using comma-separated lists (it works well here and very often).  I use a few more spaces.  I left it with the 1TBS format for the blocks of code, though I don't use that myself (I use Allman).

My draft solution used practically the same printing code as shown above, but the main `while` loop was slightly different:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %counts = ();

while (<>)
{
    $counts{$1}++ if (m/.*:(\d+):/);
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        print "$ARGV:\n";
        foreach my $number (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %counts)
        {
            print ":$number: $counts{$number}\n"
        }
        %counts = ();
    }
}
```

The only advantage over what you used is that if some line doesn't contain a colon-surrounded number, it ignores the line, whereas yours doesn't consider that possibility.  I'm not sure the comparison code in the `sort` is necessary — it ensures that the comparisons are numeric, though.  If the numbers are all the same length and zero-padded on the left when necessary, there's no problem.  If they're more generally formatted, the 'forced numeric' comparison might make a difference.

Remember: this is Perl, so TMTOWDTI (There's More Than One Way To Do It).   Someone else might come up with a simpler solution.

Answer (score -2):

Desired output can be achieved with following code snippet

- look for pattern `:\d+:` in a line
- increment hash `%count` for the digit
- output result to console

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %count;

/:(\d+):/ && $count{$1}++ for <>;

say "$_ = $count{$_}" for sort keys %count;
```